# fix the footer that cannot be adjusted full screen in bootstrap for desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css, layout, size, footer

I am intermediate in HTML and CSS so please consider that I am not advanced to understand complex concept .I am designing site .  on top I have logo and it is inside a div . below that is my navigation menu . and under there are 2 containers on Bootstrap . and container on the right is only a button inside a div that hides and unhide bunch of link .then i have a pagination and footer below it. that is all of site .
right now I have problem changing color of footer and make it full width . my problem is that it never becomes a full width and something is blocking it.in order for footer not to float upward  also i put some codes in site  .
but when i want to change the color of footer and then make footer full with this does not work and footer does not become full width . i tried to put it in  a div and did not work  .

i tried extremely hard to put my codes here on stackoverflow  but it says codes not properly formatted and i tried to fix it for 3 hours and it did not work. all my codes are verified by visual studio code and they all work. it is extremely frustrating that i could not paste my codes here .please , consider this fact ,thanks a lot

i need full width bootstrap footer that does not float up with other elements

if there is a code that works for footer with w3.css or  Tailwind.css and it is  NOT complex then please let me know . I need just a footer with 150 px height and full width of page . and nothing fancy in it just i want to write one small phrase consists of 4 words in it . i do not wanted footer with any kinds of logo,links etc ,just a plain footer.

Comment: this is footer code                                                                                                                            <footer class="container text-center " style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <p>Footer Text</p>
      </footer>                                                                                                                             if I can have a footer that is fully bootstrap or W3.CSS  or even tailwind.css and it does not float up with other elements then that is fine as well.

Comment: i had to put this html{height:  100%;  
}                                                                                                                                          and this body{

min-height: 100%;
display: flex;   flex-direction:column:
}                                                                                                                                   to stop footer from floating up

Comment: i had to put this  to prevent 2 bootstrp container that one has written content and 1 has button that hides link in it to get unadjusted margins from left and right of the webpage  here is the code for MOBILE ONLY cause mobile gave me hard time and had to insert this:                                                                                                                                   @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

width: 70%;
  }i think this code prevents me from putting 100% width footer but i need it,if i remove it then entire columns of page will be in disarray

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your code which is not getting full width, the problem here is that you do not actually understand CSS Flexbox.Also change container to container-fluid to achieve full width.

```
<footer class="container text-center " style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;"> 
<p>Footer Text</p> 
</footer>
```

You can do it like this without using flex

```
    <footer class="container-fluid text-center bg-success p-2"> 
<p>Footer Text</p> 
</footer>
```

OR if you are still insisted to use flex use bootstrap classes for this but i am changing your code as add class="w-100" to the paragraph tag" and change container to container-fluid like this...

```
<footer class="container-fluid text-center bg-success p-2" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;"> 
<p class="w-100">Footer Text</p> 
</footer>
```

Hope that make sense.Happy Coding :-)